# How to get notified when a player "Remove" a match in progress from GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, gkturnbasedmatch

I am using the default `GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController`. A player can "Remove" a match in progress by sliding the match cell to the left and then tapping the red "Remove" button. But this does not notify the other player that the first one has removed (and quit as well) the match. The other one continues to wait another player to join the match and make a turn. But this is against the logic of my game. I want to end the match as soon as any player quits the match or removes it. 
Is there any way to receive any kind of callback or set `matchOutcome` for player who wants to remove the match?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has long been a weak spot in `GKTurnBasedMatches`. Matches may be updated outside of your game,  through the match maker view controller and (in <= IOS9) the Game Center app, frequently creating unrecoverable scenarios.

[Player swipe to remove match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34994621/player-swipe-to-remove-match) describes using this same issue (but cites the now-removed Game Center app) as an exploit to avoid incurring a loss. I posted a partial work-around there, and a similar approach will help mitigate your situation, too:

1. Any time you receive an invite, join a match or create a match, store the matchID locally.
2. When the game starts, call `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler` to pull all the matches the local player knows about. Matches that the local player deleted "outside" your app will be (appropriately) missing from the server's list.
3. Even though they deleted the match from their list, they can still load the specific match using `loadMatchWithID`. So, for each "missing" match, call `loadMatchWithID` using the matchID you stored locally, get the match object, and then call either `participantQuitInTurnWithOutcome`, `participantQuitOutOfTurnWithOutcome`, or `declineInviteWithCompletionHandler` based on the player's status in the deleted match.
4. Quitting / Declining will send a notification and/or pass the turn to the other player.

Although not ideal, as long as the "deleter" starts the game again, you have a chance to evaluate all the games and force a clean exit from the matches they deleted. Calling either of the `participantQuit` functions will send a notification (and/or pass the the turn) to the other player.

This work around won't work, though, if the "deleter" never starts the game again. In that scenario, all the other player can do is eventually leave the match themselves if they haven't seen any progress after some set time interval.

Comment: Thanks, I think, your approach could be applicable for the vast majority of cases. Actually, I see another solution. It takes efforts, but seems more reliable - to use custom controller instead of standard one. In this case one can call `remove` method when a player delete a match and one can set outcome or something inside the completion handler.

Comment: I completely agree that rolling your own solution is the most effective option. But I find it disappointing since rolling your own defeats the (anticipated)benefits of the packaged API. But I have no doubt you will be happier with the outcome of your own implementation. That's the route I eventually took...I've completely replaced Game Center in my project.